# PF firewall: How to disable all filtering on loopback interface EXCEPT specific port forwarding rules?

Tags: networking, firewall, port-forwarding, pf

PF question on OS X Yosemite 10.10.4:

I know that `set skip on lo0` disables all filtering (nat and redirects) on **lo0**, but what if I need to save the httpd port forwarding rules on this interface while disabling all other filterings:

```
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8443
```

How would I do this?

**pf.conf:**

```
### MACROS
lan_int="en0"
wifi_int="en2"

###----- OPTIONS ------###    
   set block-policy drop
   set fingerprints "/etc/pf.os"
   set ruleset-optimization basic

### disable all filtering on loopback interface
   set skip on lo0

###--- NORMLIZATION ---###    
### Scrub incoming packets
   scrub in all no-df

###----- QUEUEING -----###

###--- TRANSLATION: ---###
### HTTPd Port Forwarding
   rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080
   rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to 127.0.0.1 port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8443

###---- FILTERING -----###    
### Antispoof
   antispoof log quick for { lo0 $lan_int $wifi_int }

### Block by default but open ports only for internal interface lo0
   block in log
   block out log
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I've found the answer:

use `pass on lo0 all` instead of `set skip on lo0`

Answer (score 0):

That one being placed closer to the top (as the 1st filtering rule may be) would do:

`pass quick on lo0 no state`