# Override "set skip on lo0" for PF firewall

Tags: networking, macos, firewall, port-forwarding, pf

I am using PF firewall and I want to redirect port on loopback interface, like this:

```
rdr on lo0 inet proto tcp from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.1 port 443 -> 127.0.0.1 port 6443
```

The problem is, my VPN client, when connecting, adds some pf rules dynamically and one of that rules is `set skip on lo0` (I don't see a way to skip this particular rule during setup). This rule is evaluated at the time of config loading, so all rules related to loopback interface are not effective anymore, no matter if they're before or after `set skip` - I'd like to bypass that somehow. Isn't there a way to somehow "unset" that option later in the ruleset or force pf not to respect it?

This question is similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/948084/pf-firewall-how-to-disable-all-filtering-on-loopback-interface-except-specific), however, in my case, my VPN client creates rule `set skip on lo0`, so I have no way of removing it. I cannot change VPN client either (this is work VPN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to bypass that somehow.
> Isn't there a way to somehow "unset" that option later in the ruleset or force pf not to respect it?

According to `pfctl`'s manual …

```
-O      Load only the options present in the rule file.  Other rules and options are ignored
```

… it's possible *to clear the options* using `-O`, for e. g.:

```
sudo pfctl -O -f /dev/null
```

`/dev/null` is an empty file hence all the options would be just trimmed. It might be too broad but I don't see a way to find currently effective options with `pfctl` itself.

Of course — if you have your own set of options to apply you can use that file then.

Comment: Thanks! This actually solved my problem, as `set skip` option is the only one set.